# tensorflow prediction on test dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am having trouble printing out the `prediction` on `test data`.

Can anyone help me filling in the input to `sess.run` at output step Thanks!

```
def nn_model(data):  
    convnet = conv_2d(in_data, 32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu')  
    convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 2)  

logits = nn_model(next_element)  
prediction = tf.argmax(logits, 1)  

with tf.Session() as sess:  
    sess.run(init_op)  
    sess.run(training_init_op)  
    for i in range(epochs):  
        l, _, acc = sess.run([loss, optimizer, accuracy])  

output = sess.run(prediction, ***{logits:nn_model(test_data)}***)
output = np.argmax(output)
print("The prediction for test is :", output)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've edited your question to make it readable, please use the editor to better format your code in the next time.

Answer (score 0):

On this line:

```
output = sess.run(prediction, ***{logits:nn_model(test_data)}***)
```

You seem to be trying to pass in your test data (presumably in numpy format) to your `logits`. `logits` is traditionally the name of the output of your model, which is quite confusing. In your `nn_model` function you should be returning both the logits (output of the model) and placeholders for your input. Normally you have something like this:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 1024))
labels = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None,))
```

Now your output looks something like:

```
output = sess.run(logits, feed_dict={x:test_data, y:test_labels}
```

In the case of test data you might not need to pass in labels, but if you wanted to compute accuracy you would need them, you decide depending on your need.

Here are some really nice examples you can follow:

https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples